# Magento 2 - How to validate wysiwyg editor in frontend PHTML file?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, frontend, wysiwyg

In **Magento 2.3.2**, I have added the wysiwyg editor in frontend PHTML file with the following codes.

> HTML:

```
<form class="form" action="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getSavePostUrl()); ?>" method="post" id="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset class="fieldset">
    <div class="field required">
        <label class="label" for="Post Name"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Post Name')); ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="post_name" value="" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Post Name')); ?>" class="input-text required-entry" id="post_name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field required">
        <label class="label" for="Post Content"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Post Content')); ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <textarea name="post_content" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Post Content')); ?>" class="input-text required-entry" id="post_content">
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="primary">
        <button type="submit" class="action save primary" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Save Post')); ?>">
            <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Save Post')); ?></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

> Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage',
    'mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup'
], function(jQuery){
    wysiwyg = new wysiwygSetup('post_content', {
        'width':'100%',  // defined width of editor
        'height':'300px', // height of editor
        'plugins':[{'name':'image'}], // for image
        'tinymce4':{'toolbar':'formatselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | link table charmap','plugins':'advlist autolink lists link charmap media noneditable table contextmenu paste code help table'
        }
    });
    wysiwyg.setup('exact');

    var postForm = jQuery('#post-form');
    postForm.mage('validation', {});
});
</script>
```

With the above code, `post_name` textbox validates for required-entry but `post_content` editor doesn’t.

Am I missing anything or Is there any other way to validate editor in frontend PHTML file?

Answer (score 1):

I have got the solution from https://webkul.com/blog/add-wysiwyg-editor-at-front-end-in-magento2-3/ to validate wysiwyg editor in frontend PHTML file.

Following is the complete code for that.

> HTML:

```
<form class="form" action="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getSavePostUrl()); ?>" method="post" id="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset class="fieldset">
    <div class="field required">
        <label class="label" for="Post Name"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Post Name')); ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="post_name" value="" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Post Name')); ?>" class="input-text required-entry" id="post_name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field required">
        <label class="label" for="Post Content"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Post Content')); ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
        <textarea name="post_content" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Post Content')); ?>" class="input-text required-entry" id="post_content">
        </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="primary">
        <button id="save-post" type="button" class="action save primary" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Save Post')); ?>">
            <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Save Post')); ?></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

> Javascript:

```
require([
'jquery',
'mage/mage',
'mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup'
], function(jQuery){
wysiwyg = new wysiwygSetup('post_content', {
    'width':'100%',  // defined width of editor
    'height':'300px', // height of editor
    'plugins':[{'name':'image'}], // for image
    'tinymce4':{'toolbar':'formatselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | link table charmap','plugins':'advlist autolink lists link charmap media noneditable table contextmenu paste code help table'
    }
});
wysiwyg.setup('exact');

var postForm = jQuery('#post-form');
postForm.mage('validation', {});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#save-post').click(function (e) {
        var validContent = 1;

        if (jQuery('#post_content_ifr').length) {
            var text = jQuery('#post_content_ifr').contents().find('#tinymce').text();
            jQuery('#post_content-error').remove();
            if (text === '' || text === null) {
                validContent = 0;
                jQuery('#post_content').parent().append('<div id="post_content-error" class="mage-error" generated="true">' + jQuery.mage.__('This is a required field.') + '</div>');
            }
        }

        if (jQuery('#post-form').valid() !== false && validContent) {
            jQuery('#post-form').submit();
        }
        else if (validContent == 0) {
            jQuery('#post_content-error').show();
        }
    });
});
});
```